# Create SQL query to fetch Total STB count and Total Out of sync STB Count for DVR in oms not in Enab

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create table oms1 
( run_date date
, ban varchar2(10)
, DVR_IND char(1)
, FREE_STB_IND char (1));

create table enab1 
( run_date date
, ban varchar2(10)
, DVR_IND char(1)
, FREE_STB_IND char (1));

insert into oms1 values(trunc(sysdate),'1','Y','Y');  
insert into oms1 values(trunc(sysdate),'1','Y','N'); 
insert into oms1 values(trunc(sysdate),'2','Y','N'); 
insert into oms1 values(trunc(sysdate),'3','Y','Y'); 
insert into oms1 values(trunc(sysdate),'3','Y','N'); 
insert into oms1 values(trunc(sysdate),'4','N','Y'); 

insert into enab1 values(trunc(sysdate),'1','Y','Y');  
insert into enab1 values(trunc(sysdate),'22','Y','N'); 
insert into enab1 values(trunc(sysdate),'33','Y','Y'); 
insert into enab1 values(trunc(sysdate),'44','N','Y'); 
commit;
```

Create SQL query to fetch Total STB count and Total Out of sync STB Count for DVR in oms not in Enab 
`TOTAL_STB_CNT` – count of total STB for DVR Record in OMS
`TOTAL_OOS_STB_CNT` – count to total STB for DVR Record which is in oms but not in enabler

Answer should be like below

```
RUN_DATE    TOTAL_STB_CNT   TOTAL_OOS_STB_CNT
7/17/2015          5                       4
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far?

Comment: SELECT RUN_DATE,
         COUNT (dvr_ind) AS TOTAL_STB_CNT,
         COUNT (dvr_ind) AS TOTAL_OOS_STB_CNT
    FROM oms1
   WHERE dvr_ind = 'Y'
         AND (dvr_ind IN (SELECT t1.dvr_ind as hillo
                               FROM    oms1 t1
                                    LEFT JOIN
                                       enab1 t2
                                    ON t2.ban = t1.ban
                              WHERE t2.ban IS NULL))
GROUP BY RUN_DATE

but im not getting the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you then try this query, but I do not know which database you use, and why TOTAL_OOS_STB_CNT = 4 ?

```
SELECT oms1.RUN_DATE
, COUNT (oms1.dvr_ind) AS TOTAL_STB_CNT
, (select count(*) from oms1 
   where oms1.dvr_ind = 'N' 
   and   ban not in (select ban from enab1)) AS TOTAL_OOS_STB_CNT 
FROM oms1 
WHERE oms1.dvr_ind = 'N' 
GROUP BY oms1.RUN_DATE
```

If it not work then you have to more describe the problem

It is not beautiful, but I hope it'll help

Comment: Thanks for the help but TOTAL_OOS_STB_CNT should be 4

Comment: Ok, Can you tell me why?

Comment: you need to consider FREE_STB_IND value also while calculating TOTAL_OOS_STB_CNT in OMS not in Enabler

Comment: Try this :
Create SQL query to fetch Total STB count and Total Out of sync STB Count for NO DVR in oms not in Enab 
TOTAL_STB_CNT – count of total STB for NO DVR Record in OMS
TOTAL_OOS_STB_CNT – count to total STB for NO DVR Record which is in oms but not in enabler

answer should be TOTAL_STB_CNT  = 1 TOTAL_OOS_STB_CNT = 1

Comment: You wrote that need to consider FREE_STB_IND value also while calculating. where is FREE_STB_IND ?

Comment: you can find FREE_STB_IND  in both tables as a column. if both data matches then its not a record

Comment: You did not mention FREE_STB_IND  above. Can you describe what do you want or not?

Comment: Ok, I see that you can't not explain what you want, so thank you for waste my time

Comment: insert into oms1 values(trunc(sysdate),'1','Y','Y');  
insert into oms1 values(trunc(sysdate),'1','Y','N'); 
insert into oms1 values(trunc(sysdate),'2','Y','N'); 
insert into oms1 values(trunc(sysdate),'3','Y','Y'); 
insert into oms1 values(trunc(sysdate),'3','Y','N'); these are 5 values for my first question under TOTAL_STB_CNT


insert into oms1 values(trunc(sysdate),'1','Y','N'); 
insert into oms1 values(trunc(sysdate),'2','Y','N'); 
insert into oms1 values(trunc(sysdate),'3','Y','Y'); 
insert into oms1 values(trunc(sysdate),'3','Y','N'); 
FOR TOTAL_OOS_STB_CNT